# Calculating the value at the beginning and end of a trendline - Time Series

Tags: r, regression, time-series, trend

I am working with R on a linear regression, time series. I have a dataframe that is looking like in the example, daily recordings from 1st of January 1993 until 31st of December 2010.

```
     Date        AT31102
1    1993-01-01  46.609
2    1993-01-02  42.273
3    1993-01-03  56.000
4    1993-01-04  63.348
5    1993-01-05  72.565
6    1993-01-06  70.174
.     AND
.     SO 
.     ON
6569 2010-12-26  57.664
6570 2010-12-27  62.428
6571 2010-12-28  66.436
6572 2010-12-29  54.697
6573 2010-12-30  66.665
6574 2010-12-31  52.835
```

I have done a plot, that looks like this (red trend line).

[image]

I have also made a summary of the linear regression:

```
summary (lm(df[,2] ~ df[,1]))

Call:
lm(formula = Stations[, 7] ~ Stations[, 1])

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-49.051 -14.889   0.005  13.740  97.316 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   23.201826   1.599414   14.51   <2e-16 ***
Stations[, 1]  0.001912   0.000135   14.16   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 20.6 on 6506 degrees of freedom
  (66 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.0299,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.02975 
F-statistic: 200.5 on 1 and 6506 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Now I want to calculate the trend values, the value at the beginning of the trend line and the value at the end of the trend line.

I know that I have to do something like this:

**

> Trendvalue* Year+ Absolute Term
>
> 0.001912 * 1993 + 23.201826 = 27.01244

**

But the result is wrong, as you can see on the plot. I think I might add the wrong value for the date/year? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `Date` column stored as `Date` object.

Thus, `lm` internally converting dates into numbers:

```
> a <- as.Date("1993-01-01")
> a
[1] "1993-01-01"
> as.numeric(a)
[1] 8401
```

And taking this as a first value, produces the correct trend value.

```
> 0.001912 * 8401 + 23.201826
[1] 39.26454
```

Comment: OMG, thanks! I would have never found that out by myself! Thanks!!!